# OS X - how to remove NSThemeAutosaveButton from document window

Tags: xcode, macos, nswindow

I am new to OS X development.
Right now I am working on a Document based app, and I don't need the document title and an arrow button to be clickable.
Actually, i don't need them at all.

I have already tried `window.titleVisibility = .Hidden` but it still shows the arrow button, and it is clickable.

[image]

I have found this element is an instance of `NSThemeAutosaveButton` class, and my workaround was like so:

```
let titlebar = window.standardWindowButton(NSWindowButton.CloseButton)?.superview

for view in titlebar!.subviews {
    if view.className == "NSThemeAutosaveButton" {
        view.hidden = true
    }
}
```

I was wondering if there is any other normal solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

This is called the "document versions button". Try this:

```
window?.standardWindowButton(.documentVersionsButton)?.isHidden = true
```